# how to add Android Button Click listner to add new field

Tags: android, button, onclick, android-edittext

Whenever the button is clicked , I want a new EditText filed to be visible. In the xml code, the visibitlity for EditTexts is gone, and whenever the button clicked, the new one is visibile.

Comment: you want to show the EditText when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the EditText views programmatically:

Define a LinearLayout on the xml and give it an id
and on Your code:

```
linearLayout.addView(new EditText(getContext()));
```

You can save references to your views on a list and access them from the list or iterate on it

```
EditText editText = new EditText(getContext());
editTextList.add(editText);
linearLayout.addView(editText);
```

Comment: can i do the above same thing to add new view in TableLayout which is in LinearLayout ? thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yes you can you can achieve anything  you do in xml and more if you do it programmatically, just set an id for the TableLayout and add the views you wish to add. as long as your using a ViewGroup you can attach view to it... LinearLayout extends ViewGroup and TableLayout extends LinearLayout

Comment: If it solved your issue please mark as the right answer

Answer (score 0):

EditText is view.
so You can hide or show views using setVisibility(int).

[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int))

Comment: yup i want this whenever the button clicked

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.